# Find div in td using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to get div from 15th td column and set width of div to 300px.

I have table summary to recognize the table. How to do set width?

```
<table  summary="Copy and Design RFP">
....
...
/* column15*/
<td class="ms-vb2">
    <div dir="">1/9/14 - 1st draft sent</div>
</td>
```

So far I wrote

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        if (window.location.href.indexOf("dept/mkt/Lists/Request for Projects/Active Projects.aspx") > -1) {
            $('table[summary="Copy and Design RFP"] tr td:nth-child(15)').each(function() {
                var id = $(this).find('div'); // This is not working
            });
        }
    });
```

Comment: `$('table[summary="Copy and Design RFP"] td:eq(14) div').width(300)`

Answer (score 2):

Use the `nth-child` selector:

```
$('table[summary="Copy and Design RFP"] td:nth-child(15) div').css('width', '300px');
```

Comment: You do have `metacharacters` in your selector that may need to be escapped.

Comment: Maybe you could tell us why your version works and the OP's doesn't, as you're using almost the same selector ?

Comment: OP's stopping the search at the td level, then doing an each, trying to find any divs which are children of that already child element. unless the node has `td div div`, the search will find nothing.

Comment: Not really, the `each()` is called on the single TD element, and inside it does `$(this).find('div')` where `this` would be the TD, which would be the same as your selector, so why would your selector find it and not the OP's `each()` call, however strange it is ?

Comment: My bad!! @War10ck I was referring to MarcB's answer but I was mistaken.

Answer (score 0):

I create this solution:

**js**

```
var i = 1;
$("table tr").children().each(function(){
    if(i==15){
     var div = $(this).find("div");
     $(div).attr("style","height:300px;");
    }
    i++;
});
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JHF4u/10/)